# Streaming MOVIE Python flask

Tags: python, flask, streaming, movie

I have a small project about streaming movie(720p). in Python Flask, Can anyone give me a example how to stream a video from a local disk in python flask. so its played on the homepage. What depedencies are avaible for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent article on this subject, [Video Streaming with Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask), written by **Miguel Grinberg** on his blog.

As he says and explains it very well, streaming with Flask is as simple as that:

**app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**index.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

All the details are in the article.

**From there...**

In your case the work is considerably simplified :

> to stream pre-recorded video you can just serve the video file as a
>   regular file. You can encode it as mp4 with ffmpeg, for example, or if
>   you want something more sophisticated you can encode a
>   multi-resolution HLS stream. Either way you just need to serve the
>   static files, you don't need Flask for that.

Source : [Miguel's Blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

Comment: I'm gonna use this code for a project, and (just by curiosity), what is the reason for not using the `<video>` tag in the HMTL template ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have come across manual solutions but Flask already has a helper function for you to stream media files with ease.

You need to use the `send_from_directory` method from `helpers.py` https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory

you can use it like this:

```
@app.route("/movies", methods=["GET"])
def get_movie():
    return send_from_directory(
                app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"],
                "your_movie.png",
                conditional=True,
            )
```